# Datos introducidos mediante formulario hecho en tkinter no se insertan en la base de datos

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, sqlite3

Tengo un código de Python con Tkinter donde el usuario debe introducir su email, password y un email de destino. Posteriormente estos datos se deben grabar en una base de datos sqlite, pero no consigo grabar los datos nunca.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
from tkMessageBox import *
import sqlite3

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title ("    ------- CONFIGURAR CUENTAS DE CORREO -------")
ventana.geometry ("500x250+500+250")
Label(ventana, text = "Usuario:").pack()
caja1 = Entry(ventana)
caja1.pack()

Label(ventana, text = "Contraseña:").pack()
caja2 = Entry(ventana, show = "*")
caja2.pack()

Label(ventana, text = "CorreoDestino:").pack()
caja3 = Entry(ventana)
caja3.pack()

def login():
    # Connect to database
    db = sqlite3.connect('C:\\robots\\login.db')
    c = db.cursor()

    c.execute("delete from usuarios where 1")

    usuario = caja1.get()
    contr = caja2.get()
    destino = caja3.get()

    try:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, pass, destino)  values({0},{1},{2});".format(usuario,contr,destino))
        showinfo(title = "Configuracion correcta", message = "DATOS ALMACENADOS CORRECTAMENTE")
        db.commit()
        c.close()

    except:
        showerror(title = "Configuracion incorrecta", message = "DATOS NO ALMACENADOS")
        db.rollback()


    c.close()

Button (text = "Guardar", command = login).pack()
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu codigo funciono a la perfección, soy un novato en esto de la programación, gracias por los consejos, fue bueno aprender de ti. Una vez más mil gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La consulta para insertar los datos es incorrecta, además no debes usar formateo de cadenas de Python para crear una consulta nunca, esto puede llevar a que tu código sea susceptible de ataque de inyección SQL. Deberías hacer por ejemplo:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, pass, destino)  VALUES(?, ?, ?);",
          (usuario, contr, destino)
         )
```

Ten en cuanta que **no ejecutas el *mainloop* de la aplicación** en ningún momento (a no ser que falte código). Si es así, seguramente usas el IDLE, que está escrito en Tkinter y tiene su propio *mainloop*, pero el código no va a funcionar fuera del IDLE sin él.

Ten siempre cuidado con `try-except` al manjar las excepciones, más aún en fase de desarrollo, el error sería mucho más fácil de localizar si al menos lo imprimieras, por ejemplo, si ingresas "Ricardo" en usuario obtendrías algo así:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 34, in login
>     c.execute("INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, pass, destino)  values({0},{1},{2});".format(usuario,contr,destino))
> OperationalError: no such column: ricardo
> ```

Lo cual ya te indica por donde va el error de forma bastante clara. Los valores deben ir entrecomillados en la consulta, por ejemplo esto funcionaría:

```
'INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, pass, destino)  values("{0}","{1}","{2}");'.format(usuario, contr, destino)
```

Pero repito, no uses `str.format` para esto.

Dejo el código completo con algunas modificaciones por si se quiere reproducir:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3
import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox
import traceback

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title ("    ------- CONFIGURAR CUENTAS DE CORREO -------")
ventana.geometry ("500x250+500+250")

user = tk.StringVar(ventana)
tk.Label(ventana, text = "Usuario:").pack()
caja1 = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=user)
caja1.pack()

passw = tk.StringVar(ventana)
tk.Label(ventana, text = "Contraseña:").pack()
caja2 = tk.Entry(ventana, show = "*", textvariable=passw)
caja2.pack()

mail = tk.StringVar(ventana)
tk.Label(ventana, text = "CorreoDestino:").pack()
caja3 = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=mail)
caja3.pack()

user.trace("w", lambda *args: caja1.config({"background": "#ffffff"}))
passw.trace("w", lambda *args: caja2.config({"background": "#ffffff"}))
mail.trace("w", lambda *args: caja3.config({"background": "#ffffff"}))


def check_table(conn):
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios (
                                        id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                                        usuario text NOT NULL,
                                        pass text NOT NULL,
                                        destino text
                                    ); """
                       )
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE 1")  # ? Borra todas las filas
        conn.commit()  

    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False

    return True


def get_data():
    usuario = user.get()
    contr = passw.get()
    destino = mail.get()

    valid = True
    if not usuario:
        caja1.config({"background": "#ff9999"})
        valid = False
    if not contr:
        caja2.config({"background": "#ff9999"})
        valid = False
    if not destino:
        caja3.config({"background": "#ff9999"})
        valid = False

    if valid:
        return usuario, contr, destino

    return None


def insert_user(conn, data):
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, pass, destino)
                               VALUES(?, ?, ?);''',
                       data
                      )
        conn.commit()

    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False

    return True


def login():
    path = 'C:\\robots\\login.db'
    try:
        db = sqlite3.connect(path)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        tkMessageBox.showerror(title="Configuración incorrecta",
                               message="NO HA SIDO POSIBLE CONECTARSE CON LA BD"
                               )
        return 

    if check_table(db):
        data = get_data()
        if data is not None:
            ins = insert_user(db, data)
            if ins:
                tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Configuración correcta",
                                      message="DATOS ALMACENADOS CORRECTAMENTE"
                                     )
            else:
                tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Configuración incorrecta",
                                      message="LOS DATOS NO HAN PODIDO SER ALMACENADOS"
                                     )
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showerror(title="Entrada inválida",
                                   message="TODOS LOS CAMPOS SON OBLIGATORIOS"
                                  )
    else:
        tkMessageBox.showerror(title="Configuración incorrecta",
                               message="NO HA SIDO POSIBLE ACCEDER NI CREAR LA TABLA 'usuarios'"
                              )

    db.rollback()
    db.close()

tk.Button (text = "Guardar", command = login).pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Los cambios más importantes son:

- Las excepciones aparte de producir un messagebox para el usuario se imprimen tal cual en la terminal, lo cual te ayudará a detectar posibles errores mientras desarrollas.
- Se han eliminado los imports de la forma `from modulo import *`, por norma general esto es una mala práctica.
- La función `get_data` valida que la entrada sea correcta antes de intentar insertar los datos. En este caso solo comprueba que las cajas no estén vacías, mostrando un mensaje de error y sombreando en rojo el Entry que lo esté. La podrías usar para validar los datos en si mismo, por ejemplo que el correo tenga un formato válido.
- La función `check_table` comprueba que la tabla exista, si no existe la intenta crear. Esto lo he hecho más que nada para que el código sea fácilmente reproducible para otros. Si lo dejas así, comprueba y modifica adecuadamente la estructura de la tabla.

El código se puede estructurar de otras formas, sería preferible usar POO pero esto ya requiere alejarse demasiado del código original.