# Problemas con try y except Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estuve intentando que el programa de error para comprobar la funcionalidad del `try-except` el cual tiene la función de que cuando ocurra un inconveniente me lo haga saber con un messagebox. El problema es que **el messagebox nunca aparece aun cuando el programa me da error en la consola**. Este problema me surgió también en otras funciones del programa, pero mediante un `if/else` lo pude solucionar (aunque dudo mucho que sea lo mas optimo, por eso me gustaría cambiarlo), intente también solucionarlo de esa misma forma pero me di cuenta de que era complicar las cosas, gracias de antemano.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar, messagebox
from typing_extensions import IntVar
import mysql.connector

root = tk.Tk()

# frames
fframe = tk.Frame(root)
fframe.pack()

# conexion bbdd
cnn = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost", user = "root", 
passwd = "password", database = "bbddejercicio")

##############MODIFICAR PAIS##############

try:
    def mostrar_pais():
        cur = cnn.cursor()
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = {entry_modificar.get()}"
        cur.execute(sql)
        datos = cur.fetchone()
        iso3_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[1])
        nombre_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[2])
        capital_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[3])
        moneda_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[4])
        cnn.commit()
        cur.close()

    def modificar_pais():
        cur = cnn.cursor()
        sql = f"""UPDATE countries SET ISO3 = '{iso3_entry.get()}', CountryName = '{nombre_entry.get()}',
        Capital = '{capital_entry.get()}', CurrencyCode = '{moneda_entry.get()}' WHERE id = {entry_modificar.get()}"""
        cur.execute(sql)
        cnn.commit()
        cur.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Pais modificado con exito")

except:
    messagebox.showerror("BBDD", "Ha ocurrido un error, verifique que los datos brindados son correctos")

# labels
label_modificar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Modificar pais:")
label_modificar.grid(row = 9, column = 1, sticky = "w", padx = (20, 0))

id_modificar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "ID del pais")
id_modificar.grid(row = 9, column = 3, sticky = "w")

iso3_modificar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Modificar ISO3 del pais")
iso3_modificar.grid(row = 10, column = 3, sticky = "w")

nombre_modificar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Modificar nombre del pais")
nombre_modificar.grid(row = 11, column = 3, sticky = "w")

capital_modifcar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Modificar capital del pais")
capital_modifcar.grid(row = 12, column = 3, sticky = "w")

moneda_modificar = tk.Label(fframe, text = "Modificar codigo de la moneda")
moneda_modificar.grid(row = 13, column = 3, sticky = "w")

# entries
entry_modificar = tk.Entry(fframe)
entry_modificar.grid(row = 9, column = 2)

iso3_entry = tk.Entry(fframe)
iso3_entry.grid(row = 10, column = 2)

nombre_entry = tk.Entry(fframe)
nombre_entry.grid(row = 11, column = 2)

capital_entry = tk.Entry(fframe)
capital_entry.grid(row = 12, column = 2)

moneda_entry = tk.Entry(fframe)
moneda_entry.grid(row = 13, column = 2)

# button
button_buscar = tk.Button(fframe, text = "Mostrar", command = mostrar_pais)
button_buscar.grid(row = 14, column = 2, ipadx = 5, sticky = "e", pady = (0, 20))

button_modificar = tk.Button(fframe, text = "Modificar", command = modificar_pais)
button_modificar.grid(row = 14, column = 2, ipadx = 0, sticky = "w", pady = (0, 20))


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: El try/except debe proteger la _ejecución_ de instrucciones, pero donde tú lo has puesto estás protegiendo solo la definición de las funciones. Cuando defines una función no,la,ejecutas aún, por lo que eso no ouede generar excepciones. Sería al ejecutar esas funciones donde deberías poner el try/except (o dentro de las funciones, alrededor de las instrucciones que pudieran generar excepción al ejecutarse)

Comment: @abulafia es decir que deberia poner el try/except en el boton que es el encargado de ejecutar la funcion de modificar una vez es presionado?

Comment: No, por desgracia al botón lo que le pasas es simplemente el nombre de la función a ejecutar. No se ejecuta nada en ese momento tampoco, sino cuando el botón es pulsado. Así que creo que en este caso la única alternativa es poner el try/except dentro de cada una de las funciones, aunque eso te obligue a repetir un poco lo mismo en cada función.

Comment: @abulafia Ahi lo pude solucionar con eso que me decias de ponerlo adentro de la funcion, muchas gracias por la ayuda y feliz año! :)

Comment: @abulafia un decorador podría ayudar?

Comment: @Christian en mi respuesta demuestro que los decoradores si pueden ayudar.

Comment: @DanteS. no la había leído, solo la vi de pasada >_<. Si no me decías iba a escribir una respuesta repitiendo lo que ya habías hecho

Comment: No pasa nada c: Te salvé avisándote xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explicación

Lo que está dentro del try es (como dijo @Abulafia en los comentarios) la definición de funciones. Es decir, estás comprobando si hay un error cuando creas las funciones. Sin embargo, el try-except que pusiste no se aplica cuando dichas funciones son ejecutadas (por ejemplo cuando presionas un botón).

Como no hay ningún error al crear las funciones, el bloque except no se llama.

#### Alternativa 1: Colocar el try-except dentro de cada función.

```
def mostrar_pais():
    try:
        cur = cnn.cursor()
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = {entry_modificar.get()}"
        cur.execute(sql)
        datos = cur.fetchone()
        iso3_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[1])
        nombre_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[2])
        capital_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[3])
        moneda_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[4])
        cnn.commit()
        cur.close()
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("BBDD", "Ha ocurrido un error, verifique que los datos brindados son correctos")
```

E igual con la otra función.

Por cierto, puedes crear tu propio decorador para envolver la llamada a tu función en un try-except y ahorrarte algo de copiar-pegar:

```
def try_except(callback):
    # creo la función con la que envolveré la original
    def nuevo_callback():
        try:
            # llamo a la función original
            callback()
        except:
            # si ocurre cualquier error durante la llamada de la función, mando este error.
            messagebox.showerror("BBDD", "Ha ocurrido un error, verifique que los datos brindados son correctos")

    # devuelvo la nueva función para que reemplaze la original
    return nuevo_callback

@try_except
def mostrar_pais():
    cur = cnn.cursor()
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id = {entry_modificar.get()}"
    cur.execute(sql)
    datos = cur.fetchone()
    iso3_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[1])
    nombre_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[2])
    capital_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[3])
    moneda_entry.insert(tk.END, datos[4])
    cnn.commit()
    cur.close()

@try_except
def modificar_pais():
    cur = cnn.cursor()
    sql = f"""UPDATE countries SET ISO3 = '{iso3_entry.get()}', CountryName = '{nombre_entry.get()}',
    Capital = '{capital_entry.get()}', CurrencyCode = '{moneda_entry.get()}' WHERE id = {entry_modificar.get()}"""
    cur.execute(sql)
    cnn.commit()
    cur.close()
    messagebox.showinfo("BBDD", "Pais modificado con exito")
```

Puedes modificar el decorador que te dí como quieras c:
No me dedicaré aquí a explicar como funcionan los decoradores aquí, pero esta pagina tiene algo de información: https://www.apsl.net/blog/2009/08/31/decoradores-en-python/

#### Alternativa 2: Tk.report_callback_exception

La clase Tk tiene el atributo `report_callback_exception`, el cual podemos asignarle nuestra propia función para procesar como queramos los errores que suceden dentro de los loops de Tkinter (error al hacer clic en un boton, al presionar una tecla, etc). Puedes probar agregando este código antes de iniciar el loop de Tkinter:

```
def on_error(root, exc, val, tb):
    messagebox.showerror("BBDD", "Ha ocurrido un error inesperado")

Tk.report_callback_exception = on_error
```

#### Cuidado con la inyección sql

Cito de [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL):

> Se dice que existe o se produjo una inyección SQL cuando, de alguna
> manera, se inserta o "inyecta" código SQL invasor dentro del código
> SQL programado, a fin de alterar el funcionamiento normal del programa
> y lograr así que se ejecute la porción de código "invasor" incrustado,
> en la base de datos.

Esto implica la posibilidad de que el usuario ingrese su propio código sql a travez de tu programa. Estoy seguro de que no deseas este comportamiento.

Una sección donde puede ocurrir una inyección sql es en este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si luego de escribir esto presionas modificar, la consulta resultante será la siguiente:

```
UPDATE countries SET ISO3 = '', CountryName = '', Capital = '', CurrencyCode = '' WHERE id = 1 or true
```

Una vez esta consulta se ejecute, el where siempre dará verdadero y todas las filas de la tabla countries terminarán modificadas.

Solo hace falta ver como creas la consulta para que un atacante se anime a aplicar la inyeccion sql.

[En google hay varias paginas en español que hablan de como evitar la inyección sql](https://www.google.com/search?q=como+evitar+inyeccion+sql+mysql+python&biw=1366&bih=625&sxsrf=AOaemvJhT-vqWFZ3h0GGZdeCxHoe16YGFw%3A1641054726620&ei=BoLQYdOsJd3d1sQP18WI4AY&ved=0ahUKEwjTx6Wg_ZD1AhXdrpUCHdciAmw4ChDh1QMIDw&uact=5&oq=como+evitar+inyeccion+sql+mysql+python&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgcIIxCwAxAnOggIIRAWEB0QHjoECCEQCjoHCCEQChCgAUoECEEYAUoECEYYAFDFBFjNGmCoHGgBcAB4AIABrgGIAfMJkgEDNy41mAEAoAEByAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz). Como por ejemplo esta pregunta: [Prevenir inyecciones de sql al escribir código en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/419469/prevenir-inyecciones-de-sql-al-escribir-c%C3%B3digo-en-python)